# Django South - Unable to Reset App Migrations

Tags: django, postgresql, django-south, database-migration

I'm trying to reset my south migration history and can't get migrations to run for myapp.  My settings.py is:

```
...
'south',
'myapp',
'allauth',
'allauth.account',
'allauth.socialaccount',
'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
'payments',
```

What I've tried that unfortunately isn't working for me:

1. Delete/rm all existing migration files
2. Comment out everything except for south
3. Run an initial syncdb
4. Run `./manage.py schemamigration app_name --initial` for each app
5. Then migrate apps one by one

This process works fine for everything except myapp.  When I try to do the initial migration for myapp I get:

```
hostMigrations: 
! These migrations are in the database but not on disk:
<myapp: 0002_..._>
! I'm not trusting myself; either fix this yourself by fiddling
! with the south_migrationhistory table, or pass --delete-ghost-migrations
! to South to have it delete ALL of these records (this may not be good).
```

If I pass --delete-ghost-migrations then it tells me there's nothing to migrate for myapp, which obviously isn't the case. When I --fake 0002 it tells me there's nothing else to migrate after 0002. Is there another way to approach this?

Answer (score 3):

To completely remove your migration history you need to delete every row in it's table on the database.

Go to your database and erase all rows in `south_migrationhistory` table:

```
delete from south_migrationhistory;
```

or if you want to just reset the history of a specific app you can do:

```
delete from south_migrationhistory where app_name='your_app_name';
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Out of curiosity, would `--delete-ghost-migrations` do the same thing in this case?

Comment: I think it does more than that, that's why it yield errors like above. I have stumble with resetting migrations several times and this is the most straight forward controlled completely by me full reset.

Comment: You may be right, but i would just do `delete from south_migration_history where app_name='myapp'` so I dont have to run the other migrations and get into other trouble again :). Correct me if i m wrong

Comment: You're right, I was just assuming he wanted a full reset. This indeed will reset only the app's migration. I'll correct it in my answer. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Paulo, thanks but deleting the south_migrationhistory table isn't solving the "nothing to migrate" problem with myapp. Only the initial myapp 0001 migration is appearing, but there are [00]13. south is recognizing the additional migrations for my other project apps however - what could I have done to make it ignore myapp's?

Comment: I had once and app named `messages` which conflicted with django's app `messages`. I had lot of troubles finding the migrations and doing them correctly, turn out django's messages app was the one getting migratated. Also, did you erased `migrations` folder of your app after deleting the rows in your table?

Comment: good suggestion Paulo but myapp has a unique name that definitely isn't conflicting with anything within django. I will note I only deleted all the contents of migrations folder not the actual folder itself. i'll try completely deleting the folder and see if somehow that makes a difference...